# PHP ForEach loop doesn't iterate / count

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, foreach

I'm trying to return a value to an android application in JSON format using a web service. For some reason, my code is only returning "Invalid login, please try again". I'm positive that the username is being entered, and I'm positive the tasks are returning properly. Using test code, which I've included as commented lines, I verify that the service will return one set of data to the application. It appears that the problem is with my foreach loop, but I don't see how. It's pretty simple stuff. Obviously it isn't iterating, or my count would be increasing and I wouldn't receive the Invalid Login error. The only thing I can figure is that I would need to use a nest foreach loop, but I haven't had much success with that, either.

Thanks in advance for the help, guys!

Here is the foreach loop...

```
//for reach task returned, add to array for later output
            foreach ($row2['Description'] as $t)
            {
            $taskDisplay = array('task' => $t);
            $taskCount++;
            }
```

and the count...

```
if ($taskCount > 0)    
{
echo json_encode($taskDisplay);
}
else
{
echo "Invalid login, please try again";
}
```

here is the code in full

```
$taskDisplay = array();
$taskCount = 0;

//do this portion if app gives key value "PART_ONE"
if ($result['part'] == "PART_ONE")

{   
    //if username was entered, check user credentials
    if(array_key_exists('user', $result)) {

        $usercheck = $con->prepare("Select * from Employee
                        Where usr = ?
                        and pass = ?");
        $usercheck -> execute(array($result['user'], $result['password']));
        $row = $usercheck -> fetch();

        //if username was verified, select tasks from database
        if($row['usr'])
        {

            $task = $con->prepare("Select * from Tasks
                        where Assigned_Employee = ?");
            $task -> execute(array($result['user']));
            $row2 = $task -> fetch();
            $statusCode = "Success";
            //$taskDisplay = $row2['Description'];

            //for reach task returned, add to array for later output
            foreach ($row2['Description'] as $t)
            {
            $taskDisplay = array('task' => $t);
            $taskCount++;
            }   

        }


    else
    {
    $statusCode = "Fail";
    //bail if invalid username entered
    exit;
    }


    //$arr = array('task' => $taskDisplay, 'status_code' => $statusCode);
    //echo json_encode($arr);

    if ($taskCount > 0) 
    {
    echo json_encode($taskDisplay);
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Invalid login, please try again";
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I think may be your problem within the foreach and $row2['Description'] hasn't values, that's why count not increase.

Comment: `$row2['Description']` is probably not an array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have already double checked that the SQL is returning the proper values. In the commented out code, I'm able to return a single value back to my android application.

Answer (score 0):

To `foreach` over all rows you'll want `fetchAll()`.  Then you want to access the `Description` column in each row:

```
$row2 = $task->fetchAll();

// etc...

foreach ($row2 as $t)
{
    $taskDisplay[] = array('task' => $t['Description']);
    $taskCount++;
}
```

Comment: This works, although it is still only returning one result. It should be returning two sets of data from the database.

Comment: Edited.  Need `$taskDisplay[]`

Comment: Yes, perfect!  That returns the array. I'm still having trouble actually populating the list to my android app, but that's a problem for another post.  Thank you for your help!